# Java other directory for src

Tags: java, eclipse

I have packages that don't want to place in `src` folder in order to compile. Can I setup Eclipse so that other directory along with `src` would act as a source directory?

EDIT: When I do `Build Path > Use as source folder` on the folder which contains `com/some_package/classes/*.java` then error in Eclipse disappear but in command line compile time I get `cannot find symbol` error. Whereas, when I copy the same `com.some_package/classes/*.java` into `src` directory it works in eclipse and compiles command line too. How to fix command line compilation too?

Comment: So why don't you just leave the files in `src`?

Comment: Because I need to add 7 SDK and each one has its src packages and jars. I don't what to separate them. I want to keep the structure of each SDK in one folder.

Comment: I'd ask you to give a reproducible example. It's possible Eclipse compiles different source folders separately, though I wouldn't think it should.

Comment: I cannot, as I use cocos2d-x project. Project is huge and it is being created automatically. I don't know how it works.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can select any folder in Eclipse, right click and choose `Build Path > Use as source folder`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Go to your **Project properties -> Java Build Path**. You will see *Source* tab there.
Use that to add your source directory.

Answer (score -2):

This isn't exactly an answer to your question but folks who use **IntelliJ** could just right click the directory --> **Mark Directory As** --> **Sources Root**.

Comment: Oh great. I try to pass on some information and there goes the downvote. Thanks.

Comment: The question is regarding Eclipse.

Comment: I thought it would help people using other IDE's. @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: Should we post answers for all IDEs? That would distract from the problem at hand, which is on Eclipse.

Comment: No worries. You can delete/edit your post. Since you're new, you should consider taking the tour and reading through the help center.